# post in my js wont work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

> JS : Fixed by godot!

```html
/* Data Delete Starts Here */
$(".delete-file").click(function()
{
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  var file_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var active_user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if(confirm('Sure to Delete ' +name+ '?'))
  {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'suf-delete.php',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        data: {'file_id':file_id ,'active_user':active_user},
        success: function(response){
           $("#file_table"+file_id).fadeOut('slow');
        },
        error: function(error){
              console.log(error.responseText);
         //you could debug your php code if some error raises
         }

    });
  }
  return false;
});
/* Data Delete Ends Here */
```

> PHP: Working Fine (suf-delete.php)

```html
elseif($_POST['file_id'] && $_POST['active_user'])
{
 $file_id = $_POST['file_id'];
 $active_user = $_POST['active_user'];
 $crud->filesDelete($file_id,$active_user);
}
```

Im now having a problem with my class crud.

I think Its just my query. Im trying to make activity log, delete, select and unlink Item using my code provided below.

Please check this:

> Class Crud

```html
    public function filesDelete($file_id,$active_user)
    {
      $stmtFiles = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_files WHERE file_id=:file_id');
      $stmtFiles->execute(array(":file_id"=>$file_id));
      $unFile=$stmtFiles->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $userStmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE username=:username');
      $userStmt->execute(array(":username"=>$active_user));
      $fetch = $userStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $activity = "Deleted the file ".$unFile['file_name'];
      if($fetch['access_type']=="Design2K18ADMIN") {
        $type = "Administrator";
      }
      elseif ($fetch['access_type']=="Design2K18MANAGER") {
        $type = "Manager";
      }
      elseif ($fetch['access_type']=="Design2K18MODERATOR") {
        $type = "Moderator";
      }
      elseif ($fetch['access_type']=="Design2K18SIMPLE") {
        $type = "Simple";
      }

      $actLog = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO activity_log(username, activity, type) VALUES(:username, :activity, :type)");
      $actLog->execute(array(":username"=>$active_user, ":activity"=>$activity, ":type"=>$type));

      $stmtSelFol = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tbl_section WHERE sec_id=:sec_id');
      $stmtSelFol->execute(array(":sec_id"=>$unFile['sec_id']));
      $unFol=$stmtSelFol->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      unlink("../Files/".$unFol['sec_folder']."/".$unFile['file_name']);

      $stmtDelFile = $this->conn->prepare('DELETE FROM tbl_files WHERE file_id=:file_id');
      $stmtDelFile->execute(array(":file_id"=>$file_id));

      return true;
    }
```

I have confirm that My js and php works fine by saving the logs in error.php

I save the value of file_id and active_user in my error.txt file.

9Daren appears which is the value(id) of Item and the current session user is Daren.

Please help me check my public function why It does not do anything.

Comment: have you checked the response or tried any debugging at all? Maybe try returning `$_POST['file_id']` and `$_POST['active_user']` to make sure those are being sent or dump all `$_POST[]` to see what is being posted.

Comment: Thanks for hint. Ill try and take you back what it shows.

Comment: you share half code of `elseif` share all code ?

Comment: @NewToJS I got 9Daren. which is the value of both $_POST

Comment: @C2486 other codes doesnt have to do with this code. and I found out the error in in public function.

Comment: Well if the `$post()` is posting the expected data then I can only assume it's something in the `php` that is making it stop executing before your `elseif()` statement.

Comment: @NewToJS  is right share all code or just share the error in network tab ?

Comment: @NewToJS no errors appear in network tab (inspect element) please re read my update sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `ajax`:

```
/* Data Delete Starts Here */
$(".delete-file").click(function()
{
  var name = $(this).attr("name");
  var file_id = $(this).attr("id");
  var active_user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if(confirm('Sure to Delete ' +name+ '?'))
  {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'suf-delete.php',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        data: {'file_id':file_id ,'active_user':active_user},
        success: function(response){
           $("#file_table"+file_id).fadeOut('slow');
        },
        error: function(error){
              console.log(error.responseText);
         //you could debug your php code if some error raises
         }

    });
  }
  return false;
});
/* Data Delete Ends Here */
```

Comment: error: function(error){
              console.log(error.responseText);
         //you could debug your php code if some error raises
         }

Comment: is it alright I save error.txt to error so I can see it?

Comment: does your ajax execute success function or error function ?

Comment: It works fine thanks. Ill update my query. I am now having trouble with public funtion.

Comment: is it another question? or can I help you?

Comment: it just doesnt perfform delete?

Comment: in your suf-delete.php snipped you have elseif block, please write full block. Maybe problem is not in your funciton

Comment: thanks my error is activity_log. because I use activity_logs in my database hahahha Thanks so mcuh